# How to pass Serizalizer Fields to front-end Framework from RESTful API - DRF (Django)?

Tags: javascript, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I want to use Svelte in the front-end and DRF (Django) in the back-end.

This is what I have right now:

```
#models.py
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

```
# serializers.py
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = "__all__"
```

But when I know want to create a form in the front-end (Svelte) I have to manually do that? Is there a way of requesting a json with all the required fields and the to build a form around it.

Like first I request `api.com/students/form` which returns a json:

```
{
  "fields":[
    "first_name",
    "last_name"
  ]
}
```

And then I could just iterate over the fields in `"fields"` and create `<input>` tags for the form accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by accessing metadata of the url, simply send `OPTIONS` request to the endpoint as suggested in [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/)

Comment: I think I'd rather use OpenAPI. But I don't understand how to get only the OpenAPI spec for one endpoint.